# Bryntum Calendar recurance Extjs with google icalendar

Tags: java, extjs, icalendar, bryntum-scheduler

I'm using Extjs Bryntum Calendar to create events and want to save them as google ics file and load events again into Sch calendar.

Can any body tell how to convert from Cal.model.Event to ical events and vice versa?
data come from api as ical data.

my code IS:

resource store:

```
Ext.define('my.store.CalendarResource', {
    extend: 'Cal.data.ResourceStore',
    storeId: 'resource',
//    proxy: 'memory',
    model:'my.model.CalendarResource',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'api/calendars/scheduler'
    },

});
```

resource model:

```
Ext.define('my.model.CalendarResource', {
    extend : 'Cal.model.Resource',

   fields: [{
        name: 'Id',
        type:'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Color',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'data'
    }]
});
```

calendar view

```
Ext.define('my.view.RecurrenceCalendar', {
    extend : 'Cal.panel.Calendar',
    xtype  : 'recurrencecalendar',
    
    requires : [
        'Sch.data.util.recurrence.Legend',
        'my.store.CalendarEvent',
        'my.store.CalendarResource'
    ],

    date          : new Date(),
    eventStore    : 'event',
    resourceStore : 'resource',

    // show the resource filter
    resourceFilter : {
        dock : 'right'
    },

    // Uncomment the below line to disable the recurring events feature
//     recurringEvents : false,

    initComponent : function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {
            eventRenderer : function (eventRecord, resourceRecord, tplData) {
                var legend = '';

                if (me.recurringEvents && eventRecord.getRecurrence()) {
                    legend = Sch.data.util.recurrence.Legend.getLegend(eventRecord.getRecurrence(), eventRecord.getStartDate());
                }

                return eventRecord.getName() + (legend ? ' | ' + legend : '');
            },
            beforeeventadd : function (me, eventRecord, resources, eOpts) {
                var resourceStore = me.getResourceStore();
                alert('aaaaaaa')
            }
        });
        me.on('eventclick', function ( view, record, e ) {
            var el = e.getTarget(me.getSchedulingView().eventSelector, 10, true);

            me.editor.edit(record, el);
        });
        me.on('eventdbclick', function ( view, record, e ) {
            var el = e.getTarget(me.getSchedulingView().eventSelector, 10, true);

            me.editor.edit(record, el);
        });
        me.on('beforeeventadd',function(me, eventRecord, resources, eOpts){
            alert('123')
        });
        Ext.getStore('resource').reload();
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    
    onEventCreated : function (newEventRecord, resources) {
        // Overridden to provide some default values

        var resourceStore = this.getResourceStore();

        if (!newEventRecord.getResourceId()) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(resources)) {
                newEventRecord.assign(resources);
            } else if (resourceStore && resourceStore.getCount() > 0) {
                newEventRecord.assign(resourceStore.first());
            }
        }
    },
    
    
});
```

event store:

```
Ext.define('my.store.CalendarEvent', {
    extend  : 'Cal.data.EventStore',
    storeId : 'event',

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you done?

To save records as iCalendar file:

You can serialize records from `store` to format `.ical` format (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt).

To load file as events:

Ex. you can listen `change` in `file` input and decode `.ical` format to your model parameters.

You can use existing open source library like https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js

Comment: Thank you Mr,
Do you know how can I catch event creation from the calendar eventEditor to convert it to .ical format?

Comment: You can listen on `add` event on `store` like `Ext.getStore('event').on('add', function (store, records, index, eOpts) {
// do something with records
});`